# cirq_google library in Python

Tags: programming, cirq

I am trying to use the cirq_google library in Python but I receive an error:

```
# from cirq        import Simulator
# !pip install cirq_google 
from cirq_google import XmonSimulator
```

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'XmonSimulator' from 'cirq_google' (unknown location)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `XmonSimulator` is no longer supported: [#1978](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/issues/1978), [#1993](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/pull/1993).

You should instead use `cirq.Simulator`: [#3277](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/issues/3277#issuecomment-682692431).

Comment: You mean the first commented line?

Comment: Yes, the first line